# Typeorm Error ColumnTypeUndefinedError: Column type for #name is not defined and cannot be guessed

Tags: typescript, typeorm

var decorated = decorator(target, propertyKey, descriptor);
^
ColumnTypeUndefinedError: Column type for Author#name is not defined and cannot be guessed. Make sure you have turned on an "emitDecoratorMetadata": true option in tsconfig.json. Also make sure you have imported "reflect-metadata" on top of the main entry file in your application (before any entity imported).If you are using JavaScript instead of TypeScript you must explicitly provide a column type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into your `tsconfig` file and uncomment `"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,` then install `reflect-metadata` and go into your application entry file, for example, app.ts or index.ts or server.ts depending on how you called it, and import `reflect-metadata`  follow the steps below

```
npm install reflect-metadata

import "reflect-metadata";
```